# 2003-2006 Honda Accord v6 - ATF refill amount

Tags: honda, transmission, accord

Greetings one and all,

I recently changed the transmission on my 03 Honda Accord V6 (Original could not go into reverse), I am trying to find out how much transmission fluid I should put back in it, I did some research online and some folks are saying 7 Quarts and some are saying 12. Can anyone here provide me with a credible answer to this question please?

I am trying to get my hands on a manual or someone from the Honda dealership to verify. If I find the info I will post the answer here, assuming no one replies before then.

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to page 364 of the [Owner's Manual](http://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/AH/AAC0303OM/enu/AC0303OM.pdf), the V6 model has a capacity of 6.9 to 7.6 US quarts.

If you did not drain the torque converter, you should start with the "change" amount, then check levels.

**Do not over fill it.**

*Note: unsure if you have the coupe or sedan. I selected the manual for the sedan. I would thing the capacities would be the same, but check anyway.*

Comment: I do have the Sedan, but  Thank you so much for the answer and the manual.